# Как создать напоминалку о том, что необходимо закрыть PrintWriter, если он входит в состав метода-логгера?

Tags: java, логирование, запись

```
    1. Report.initialize(level.low, display.on);
    2. Settings.initialize();
    3. Profile.initialize();
    4. History.initialize();
    5. Report.close();
```

Как в теле класса Report создать напоминалку о том, что в 5 строке мне необходимо закрыть PrinWriter?
Хотелось бы, чтобы на полях рабочего листа Eclipse появлялась отметочка-напоминание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если речь именно об Eclipse, то вы можете оствить себе TODO.

- включите Task Tags: **General > Editors > Structured Text Editors > Task Tags > Enable searching for Task Tag**s
- ключевые слова для поиска для Java файлов можно добавить в **Java > Compiler > Task Tags**

Потом, просто оставляете комментарий в любом месте кода, содержащий ключевое слово TODO (FIXME etc..), и он у вас будет отображаться во вьюшке **Markers**.

Но в целом, такой метод никогда не используется. Во первых, если вы не закроете поток, Eclipse вам и так покажет маркер "Resource Leak...". Во вторых, для этого используются специальные инструменты, выполняющие статический анализ кода. Поставьте плагин **FindBugs**, он довольно просто настраивается. И в третьих, вы можете не закрывать поток, если используете конструкцию [try-with-resources](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/try-with-resources.html)